# Аутентификация приложения java + spring через сторонний сервис

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Делаю сервис на java + spring, который аутентифицируется через стороннюю систему.
Т.е. в запросе от клиента приходит токен, я делаю запрос в стороннюю систему с этим токеном, получаю данные пользователя. После этого я сохраняю данные у себя в бд, генерирую свой токен, отдаю пользователю и далее уже работаю через него.

Первоначально я сделал jwt, что позволило не хранить в бд лишней информации и все работает просто и быстро. Но возникло требование безопасности уметь отзывать токен. Я могу сделать велосипед, класть в jwt какой-нибудь session_id, который будет храниться в бд, и при каждом запросе проверять не отозван ли он.

Но велосипеды писать не хочется и я обратил внимание на oauth2 с хранением в jdbcTokenStore. В перспективе auth-server пригодился бы и для других проектов.  Но чем дальше я разбираюсь с ним, тем больше понимаю что он плохо ложится на эту концепцию. Получается что роль клиента и ресурса будет играть один и тот же сервис. А в сервисе авторизации не будет храниться пароль. Придется писать самому методы создания и обновления пользователя и т.д. И еще @EnableAuthorizationServer в последнем обновлении объявили deprecated, а в руководстве по миграции написано, что новая версия пока в разработке.

Теперь у меня новая идея использовать сессии (кука JSESSIONID). Узлов будет несколько, поэтому хранить сессию придется в бд. В будущем выбью под это дело redis.

Что скажете, не упустил ли я чего? Какое решение будет здесь оптимальным?
К сожалению времени остается мало, нужно принимать решение и согласовывать его с безопасниками.